# Storing environment variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am currently developing an application for Angular 2 based on [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed). I am looking what the best way is to store enviroment variables so I can store different values for, for example, a API url.

The default config file (**seed.config.ts**) already has 2 environments that are used when building for production or development:

```
/**
 * The enumeration of available environments.
 * @type {Environments}
 */
export const ENVIRONMENTS: Environments = {
  DEVELOPMENT: 'dev',
  PRODUCTION: 'prod',
  STAGING: 'staging'
};
```

Further in this config file, a class SeedConfig is defined that has some constants defined, I guess this would be the place where I should add my variables as wel. That gives me:

```
export class SeedConfig {

  PORT = argv['port'] || 8000;
  URL_DEV = 'www.example.com';
  URL_PROD = 'www.example.com';
```

Now what would be the best approach to access these variables in my template, based on the configured environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**

Provide the class

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide('SeedConfig', {useClass: SeedConfig}]);
```

or

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  providers: [provide('SeedConfig', {useClass: SeedConfig}],
  ...
})
```

access it like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `<div>{{seedConfig.DEVELOPMENT}}</div>
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('SeedConfig') private seedConfig:any) {}
}
```

**2)**

or alternatively to get proper autocompletion

Provide the class

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [SeedConfig]);
```

or

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  providers: [SeedConfig],
  ...
})
```

access it like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `<div>{{seedConfig.DEVELOPMENT}}</div>
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private seedConfig:SeedConfig) {}
}
```

The 2nd approach has the advantage that autocompletion can list all configured properties but it also requires `SeedConfig` to be imported everywhere, where it is used.

Comment: Hmm there is 1 point where I'm not sure how to proceed, I don't need the variables in my template, but in my component. How can I access these variables in the component?

Comment: Just `this.seedConfig.DEVELOPMENT`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer would it be wrong to save these variables in environment.ts?

Comment: @Sofia I don't understand the question. Why would it be wrong? It usually depends on the context.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I guess wrong is not the right word, but is it bad practice to save constants in the environment.ts? I am looking for a place to put constants, so that I can use them throughout the application : )

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting constants there if you want to deploy the applications multiple times with different values or if you want to have different values between development, staging, productions, ...